# Permute the parameters in a parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have two structures

```
template <int ... values>
struct foo {}

template <int ... values>
struct lists {}
```

I want to have a function `bar` that takes the `lists` and `foo` and permutes parameters of `foo` to return another `foo`

```
another_foo bar(lists<0,3,1,2>, foo<4,5,6,7>)
```

I want the type of `another_foo` to be `foo<4,7,5,6>` so basically sort one parameter in terms of another. I also want the function to work with arbitrary parameters in list not necessarily as index to `foo` parameters, such as

```
another_foo bar(lists<20,12,21,13>, foo<4,5,6,7>)
```

I want `another_foo` to be type alias to `foo<6,4,7,5>`. In this case, `lists<20,12,21,13>` is basically another version of `lists<2,0,3,1>` as in terms of ascendency that is how the elements are arranged. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Its the same rule, for no matter how many arguments, such as `bar(lists<1,2,0>, foo<3,2,5>)` should return `foo<2,5,3>`. Of course exception is empty `lists` and `lists` of one element   on which you obviously can't do permutation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr size_t count_less(const int (&seq)[N], int i, size_t cur = 0) {
    return cur == N ? 0
                    : (count_less(seq, i, cur + 1) + (seq[cur] < i ? 1 : 0));
}

template<class List, class Foo, class Seq>
struct meow;

template<int... ls, int... fs, size_t... ss>
struct meow<lists<ls...>, foo<fs...>, std::index_sequence<ss...>>{
    constexpr static int lst[] = { ls... };
    constexpr static int fvals[] = {fs...};
    using type = foo<fvals[count_less(lst, lst[ss])]...>;
};

template<int... ls, int... fs>
auto bar(lists<ls...>, foo<fs...>)
    -> typename meow<lists<ls...>, foo<fs...>, 
                     std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(ls)>>::type;
```

Comment: I get out of bounds error, when I try your code. Here is a [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6faf12f6905c76bd)

Comment: @TasamFarkie typo, should be `<`. Fixed.